# If I get my heart points (from cycling), should I care about getting my steps in?

Tags: gps-tracking, fitness, google-fit

Just started using Google Fit. I cycle fairly regularly, and quickly hit my target heart points per week - but I'm rarely hitting my steps goals per day. Does this matter? If I'm getting my exercise from cycling, can I just ignore the steps goal?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Just for clarification, I assume this question is specifically about how the Google Fit app works instead of health matters in general. Just in case you might be interested, we have a sister site for [fitness.se] :)